# Is there a way to retrieve FB Page information to display on my existing site

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to create an online directory site for business listings for my local area, and I would like to pull the information such as info, pics, and events off of their Facebook page instead of holding the data locally.

I was wondering if there was anyway of doing this for multiple pages. I've seen a lot of examples where you update your own status through FB connect, but I need to pull other's date to display via PHP. Any in site on this would be helpful, thank you a head of time.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Facebook Graph API (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) for a Page you can access their feed, their photos and their events. These will include links to actual pictures. You'll need to setup a Facebook App so you can authenticate yourself, but you can use an App Login token to access all the data you need.